# Update Cell If another cell is not empty

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

There are two columns N and O.

[image]

When any cell in column **N** is filled the adjoining cell in column **O** needs to filled with "**Yes**" if not it stays empty.

This is the script I'm using.

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if( s.getName() == "Sheet 1" ) 
    {
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
           if( r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == '') 
           {
              var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
                  nextCell.setValue("YES");
           }
    }
```

How can I change/modify the above script to show if when a cell is filled in a particular column then the adjoining cell shows as "Yes"

Or simply put translate this formula into a script

```
=if(ISBLANK(N2),"","Yes")
```

Without using it in this form

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("C2:C1000");
cell.setFormula("=if(ISBLANK(N2),"","Yes")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this formula :

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="INVOICE NO.","SUPPLIER MAIL",IF(ISBLANK(A$1:A),"","YES")))`

And erase any manual value under `B1`.
This should work.

Comment: Include ARRAY_CONSTRAIN to avoid filling the blank rows with a empty text value otherwise this will make the spreadsheet recalculation slower. By the other hand, instead of `""`, it's better to leave the argument empty (while other spreadsheet apps don't allow this, Google Sheets does).